# ASP.NET Core Web API POST request works with Postman but not in C#/React

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Contact Us page created in React that has three fields(Name,Email,Message), when I click the Submit button, it does not send an email to the specified user. When I used Postman to test my Web API created in C#, it sends the email correctly. I don't know what's happening since it does not throw any error.

I'm using using using System.Net.Mail; to perform smtp emails.

```
 Here is my web api code:
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(Contact contact)
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
        {
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(contact.Email);
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(_email);

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_email, _password);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to))
            {
                message.Subject = $"Hello {contact.Name}...";
                message.Body = contact.Message;

                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (SmtpException smtp)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(smtp);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my React code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (trigger) {
       axios({
          method: "post",
          url: `${proxy} + ${url}`,
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          data: data,
       }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.config.data);
     });
  }
}, [trigger]);
// My code performs post request when the submit button is changed.
// When the submit button is clicked,it sets the trigger's state to true to perform the post request.
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Edit: Added Request Headers + Response Tab:

[image]

Edit: Added Project Structure

[image]

Comment: Can you show the response tab + request headers?

Comment: Is your web API within the same project/host as your react code? I think you have a CORS issue and the reason why PostMan works is because it doesnt care about CORS but web browsers do. here is a guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware

Comment: @dariogriffo I have added the response tab and request headers above, thanks.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, Andrew is correct, my issue is with the CORS. Thanks